# Setting private variable on class

Tags: php

I'm trying to set a private variable array on my class. But I'm getting an error. Is this even possible? In other words, can I define a variable with a key - or is it bad practice?

```
class SomeClass
{
    private $result['results'] = array();

    ....
```

Error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';'`

Comment: not sure what you are planning to do...

Comment: I'm building an object, adding values to the `results` array. I just need to access this in a separate method, so wanted to set it as a class variable.

Comment: Just define `private $result = array();` If you want to add sub arrays fo rit when you need them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access the key `'results'` of that property `result` later, you should declare it like this first:

```
class SomeClass
{
    private $result = array(
        'results'  => array(),
    );

   ....
```

Although you can also have only defined the property `result` and added the `results` key later, but you can run on problems like `'undefined index ...'` exceptions if you tried to access `results` before adding the `'results'` key to the `result` property.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is possible but not in the way you are doing it. 
try

```
private $result = array();
```

and then, you can create a function to push things in the array, something like

`public function __set($key, $value){
    $this->result[$key] = $value;
}`

then, push what you want into the array calling your function

```
__set('private','this is my private array');
```